# Syntax Error line 0, col 73: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AND'

Tags: php, symfony

I am using a **Symfony 4** project, and I want to change the user password, so I created a method in my repository and called it to the controller, but this error it diplay to me,

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 73: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AND'
```

**Repository Method**

```
public function updateU($password,$email): ?Utilisateur
{
    $result= $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createQueryBuilder()
                  ->update(Utilisateur::class,'u')
                  ->set('u.password',':password')
                  ->where('u.email',':email')
                  ->setParameter('password',$password)
                  ->setParameter('email',$email)
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getSingleScalarResult();  
    return $result;

}
```

**Controller Method**

```
/**
 * @Route("/Reset", name="Reset")
 * Method({"GET"})
 */
public function New(
    Request $request,
    UtilisateurRepository $URe,
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder,
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    MailerInterface $mailer
) {
    $o = '';
    $Varmail = $_GET['email'];

    $user = new Utilisateur($o);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $to = $Varmail;
        $sujet = 'Password Changed';
        $Message = "Bonjour $Varmail Votre password est changé !";
        $pass = $user->setPassword(
            $userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('password')->getData()
            )
        );

        $URe->updateU($pass, $Varmail);

        $Mai = new MailerController();
        $Mai->sendEmail($mailer, $to, $sujet, $Message);
    }
    return $this->render('modifier_mdp/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

How can i solve it , And Thanks

Comment: why you dont just get the user entity via the email parameter and flush the change out?

Comment: `->where('u.email',':email')` should be `->where('u.email = :email')`

Answer (score 0):

Is incorrect the queryBuilder. Remember when you are using the querybuilder is makinng a construction of a DQL != SQL, try with this:

```php
public function updateU($password,$email): ?Utilisateur
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQueryBuilder()
               ->update(Utilisateur::class,'u');
    $qb
           ->where($qb->expr()->eq('u.password',':password'))
           ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('u.email',':email'))
           ->setParameter('password',$password)
           ->setParameter('email',$email);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();  
}
```

or:

```php
public function updateU($password,$email): ?Utilisateur
{
    $dql = <<<DQL
SELECT u
FROM Utilisateur::class u
WHERE u.email = :email
AND u.password = :password
DQL;

   return $this->entityManager->createQuery($dql)
               ->setParameters(['email' => $email, 'passowrd' => $password])
               ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Both uses are correct . Doctrine uses DQL to construct the real QUERY other way to corroborate this query when you use the class createQueryBuilder is the next:

```php
$qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

This function will return the real SQL to be executed in the BD server, without the parameters.

Comment: For the first Solution , it shows me this problem : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 32: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got 'WHERE'